# Registering for Push Notification

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, push-notification

I have disabled Push notification from my device settings application (Inside my app icon under settings) and when I call following piece of code none of my delegate call back gets called.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge|UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert|UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound];

application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:
application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:
```

Is there any way to know before registering for Push what all notification types have been switched on? In my application, I am proceeding further once I receive the device token in didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken call back. Now, if user do not select any one of them I cannot proceed further so wanted to give an alternate path also.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use

```
UIRemoteNotificationType notificationTypes = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] enabledRemoteNotificationTypes];
```

And then check the returned bit mask for what is and isn't enabled

```
if (notificationTypes == UIRemoteNotificationTypeNone) {
    // Do what ever you need to here when notifications are disabled
} else if (notificationTypes == UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge) {
    // Badge only
} else if (notificationTypes == UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert) {
    // Alert only
} else if (notificationTypes == UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound) {
    // Sound only
} else if (notificationTypes == (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)) {
    // Badge & Alert
} else if (notificationTypes == (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)) {
    // Badge & Sound        
} else if (notificationTypes == (UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)) {
    // Alert & Sound
} else if (notificationTypes == (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)) {
    // Badge, Alert & Sound     
}
```

You can read more in [the docs here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006728-CH3-SW52)

Comment: Thanks. This works but it do not read the individual flags separately. If there is only one flag enabled (Sound/Alert/Badge) we can read it but if more than one flag is enabled, we did not get value. Any clue how to handle this. I want to read all these flags differently.

Comment: As the value returned is a bit-mask, you'll need to test for every possible combination manually. I've updated my answer above to demonstrate this.

Comment: bdmontz answer is the right way when comparing bit-masks. Above example is unnecessarily complex.

Answer (score 9):

I realize this is getting fairly old, but there is a much better way to check which bits are set in a bitmask. First of all, if you only want to check if at least one bit is set, check if the whole bitmask is not zero.

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] enabledRemoteNotificationTypes] != 0) {
    //at least one bit is set
}
```

And if you want to check for specific bits being set, logically AND whichever bit you want to check with the bitmask.

```
UIRemoteNotificationType enabledTypes = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] enabledRemoteNotificationTypes];
if (enabledTypes & UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge) {
    //UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge is set in the bitmask
}
```

Comment: It gives me always UIRemoteNotificationTypeNone on iOS 7. Any reason?